# Problems uploading to SBT plugin releases

Tags: scala, sbt

My build.sbt has the following:

```
publishMavenStyle := false

publishArtifact in Test := false

publishTo := {
  Some(
    Resolver.url(
      "sbt-plugin-releases",
      new URL("http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/")
    )(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
  )
}
```

But when trying sbt publish or sbt publishSigned I get a 405 error:

java.io.IOException: PUT operation to URL http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.sksamuel.scoverage/sbt-scoverage/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.95.0/jars/sbt-scoverage.jar failed with status code 405: Method Not Allowed

My credentials are valid. They worked in the past and I've just double checked them.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

Updated the build to use https fixed it.
Also I tried using bintray and that works too.

Comment: You may want to use `url` for `new URL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the community repo is migrating to bintray. There's [an instruction](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/docs/Community/Bintray-For-Plugins.html) already on the site:

> sbt hosts their community plugin repository on Bintray. Bintray is a repository hosting site, similar to github, which allows users to contribute their own plugins, while sbt can aggregate them together in a common repository.

Comment: Ok I see they've literally just migrated it, thanks. The user guide screenshots are 404's at the moment so I'll have to wait before I can complete setup :)

Comment: Huh, so two things:

(1) you shouldn't have to migrate to bintray yet.
(2) I think you may need to use HTTPS.   Are you using the encrypted credentials?

Comment: Yes I was using encrypted credentials. Switching to https fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

That may have also been caused by a temporary issue on our side (bintray's). Can you try that again?

Comment: This wasn't using bintray before, but now I am and its working.